# AzureOpenAIModelFactory StreamingChatCompletions throws System NullReferenceException

Tags: azure, azure-openai

Calling the AzureOpenAIModelFactory.StreamingChatCompletions() method never works and always results in an immediate System.NullReferenceException.

This seems to be due to the internal constructor calling .Add() on a private field that hasn't been initialized at that point.

```
public class StreamingChatCompletions : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IList<ChatCompletions> _baseChatCompletions;

    //...
        
    internal StreamingChatCompletions(
            ChatCompletions baseChatCompletions = null,
            List<StreamingChatChoice> streamingChatChoices = null)
    {
        _baseChatCompletions.Add(baseChatCompletions);
        _streamingChatChoices = streamingChatChoices;
        _streamingTaskComplete = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AzureOpenAIModelFactory class seems to use the one that does not initialize the variable that is causing the nullreference. I have raised the backlog item to check on this.